# Mysql select into PHP associative array not working

Tags: php, mysql, select, associative-array

I was trying to get the response from an SQL select statement but when I try to echo the array encoded to JSON I don't have anything written except the "-" I echo to ensure myself that is entering into the loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PREGUNTA WHERE PREGUNTA.pregunta LIKE '%$palabra_clave%' OR PREGUNTA.respuesta_correcta LIKE '%$palabra_clave%' OR PREGUNTA.respuesta_falsa_1 LIKE '%$palabra_clave%' OR PREGUNTA.respuesta_falsa_2 LIKE '%$palabra_clave%' OR PREGUNTA.retroalimentacion LIKE '%$palabra_clave%'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$json = array();

while($data = $query->fetch_assoc()){
  $json[] = array(
      'pregunta' => $data['pregunta'],
      'respuesta_correcta' => $data['respuesta_correcta'],
      'respuesta_falsa_1' => $data['respuesta_falsa_1'],
      'respuesta_falsa_2' => $data['respuesta_falsa_2'],
      'retroalimentacion' => $data['retroalimentacion']
  );

    echo $data['pregunta'];
    echo '<br>';
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

And I this is my output:

```
¿Cuál no es un lenguaje de programación web?
¿Cuál es el lenguaje web más importante?
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard 5 I have cheked the error logs and I don't have any error about the query. Also if the query wouldn't be well written it wouldn't enter in the loop I think.

Comment: The query is the only explanation. How many times is the `-` echoed? Once? Definitely the query.

Comment: Add some error checking in your script - there are lots of scenarios where nothing will be written to mysql's error log, and nothing here which writes to the webserver error log.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Actually I edited my post so to see if I'm getting good results from my query and the query seems to work fine. I changed the "-"  to echo the db information. It seems that the array is the problem but certainly I am not completely sure.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Also, make sure you have PECL json installed. Maybe test something you know works like `echo json_encode(array('message' => 'test'));`

Comment: @JayBlanchard I added the lines to the top of my file but the result is the same, I don't get any error/warning printed.

Comment: Are you running this on a web server?

Comment: @toomanyredirects if I echo $json["pregunta"]; it shows me the information of the array so the only problem I think it could be is the json_encode

Comment: @toomanyredirects and if I write echo json_encode($json["pregunta"]); it prints me nothing.

Comment: Add as last line `echo json_last_error_msg();` and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your input does not use the UTF-8 character encoding. According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for `json_encode` "All string data must be UTF-8 encoded".

When I pass an array containing "¿Cuál no es un lenguaje de programación web?" to `json_encode`, it works fine. But if I first convert the text to ISO-8859-1, `json_encode` returns boolean `false` and therefore outputs nothing.

Assign your variables to the array with (eg):

```
$json[] = array('pregunta' =>
    mb_convert_encoding($data['respuesta_correcta'], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1'),
    // ...
);
```

or convert your database and application to use UTF-8 to start with.

Comment: That was the problem. Now it works really good converting the encoding, but the server conection is in UTF8_general_ci, the database is in UTF8-spanish_ci and the tables are in UTF8-spanish_ci. Do you have any idea why I am having this problem?

Comment: Have a browse through [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). Chances are something in your stack isn't configured to use UTF-8 correctly.